# Error when adding multiple rows to a table

Tags: mysql

I get 3 errors when I try to add multiple rows to a table in MySQL, here's my code I'm not sure why I'm getting the errors.

```
INSERT INTO Services (Name, Cost, Description)
VALUES('Motherboard', '30.0', 'Min printed circuitboard'),
VALUES('Power supply', '30.0', 'internal device that powers the computer'),
VALUES('CPU', '50.0', 'Processor of the computer'),
VALUES('GPU', '60.0', 'Processes graphics for computer'),
VALUES('Hard drive', '20.0', 'Storage device for computer'),
VALUES('Optical drive', '15.0', 'Reads/writes cds/dvds'),
VALUES('RAM', '30.0', 'Random access memory for computer'),
VALUES('virus removal', '24.99', 'Removes viruses from computer'),
VALUES('Internet setup', '50.0', 'setup router and devices in home'),
VALUES('1hr training', '20.0', 'Training for any of our programs'),
VALUES('Data recovery', '30.0', 'Recover data from laptop/computer'),
VALUES('install software', '15.0', 'install software on your computer'),
VALUES('Hardware fault diagnostic', '50', 'Find whats wrong with your computer/laptop'),
VALUES('laptop screen fixes', '40.0', 'Fix laptop screen'),
VALUES('monitor fixes', '40.0', 'Fix monitor screen'),
VALUES('network repairs', '30.0', 'Fix any issues with a home network');
```

And the error I get is:

```
3 errors were found during analysis.

An opening bracket followed by a set of values was expected. (near "VALUES" at position 111)
Unexpected token. (near "VALUES" at position 111)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "VALUES" at position 111)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many **values** you need only one

```
INSERT INTO Services (Name, Cost, Description)
VALUES('Motherboard', '30.0', 'Min printed circuitboard'),
('Power supply', '30.0', 'internal device that powers the computer'),
('CPU', '50.0', 'Processor of the computer'),
('GPU', '60.0', 'Processes graphics for computer'),
('Hard drive', '20.0', 'Storage device for computer'),
('Optical drive', '15.0', 'Reads/writes cds/dvds'),
('RAM', '30.0', 'Random access memory for computer'),
('virus removal', '24.99', 'Removes viruses from computer'),
('Internet setup', '50.0', 'setup router and devices in home'),
('1hr training', '20.0', 'Training for any of our programs'),
('Data recovery', '30.0', 'Recover data from laptop/computer'),
('install software', '15.0', 'install software on your computer'),
('Hardware fault diagnostic', '50', 'Find whats wrong with your computer/laptop'),
('laptop screen fixes', '40.0', 'Fix laptop screen'),
('monitor fixes', '40.0', 'Fix monitor screen'),
('network repairs', '30.0', 'Fix any issues with a home network');
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, I thought you needed the values keyword for every row you want to insert